# After rooting- apps on SD card seemingly non-existant

Tags: rooting, root-access, external-sd

I have rooted my phone 2 days ago using iRoot (well, actually, a couple of rooting softwares that failed on me before using iRoot). To be safe, I removed my sim card AND sd card before performing the process of rooting. It was a pretty straight forward process (as with many of the "one-click" rooting mechanisms readily available).
I was slightly concerned afterwards as to where all my apps had gone missing to. You see, most of my apps were installed to SD card anyway, and those that were not were copied there (e.g Du battery saver). I suffered pretty much the same problem as this guy- ([can't find apps on sd card after root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/cant-find-apps-on-sd-card-after-root))

Rebooting and even factory resetting the phone on multiple times did nothing to "revive" the apps. The SD card size is the same as it was before the root, so the apps are definitely still there. The app data is still there also...so I am really confused as to why the apps are not showing up.

Because I needed to get on whatsapp for days, I decided to just re-install the app again and upon doing so it let me know that it was detecting some chat backups and restored the app almost fully to its original state before the root.

After searching around online I couldnt really find many other people in a similar predicament. It seems rather odd.

Could anyone provide some insight into this?

(My phone specs- spreadtrum with froyo...I suspect)

Edit- Forgot to say thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the installed apps to SD Card are not technically installed on SD card ,the android system move a part of the apk file to the SD card but not the full apk there for after a factory reset your apps installed on sd card will not be available for use since they are not real apks.

the android system move the apks to `.android_secure` directory on the sd card you can see it via a file manager app like es explorer after activating the show hidden folders under (es explorer > settings > view settings > show hidden files and folders) and that's why the size of you sd card didn't change because the data is still there but not usable.

so to answer your question your apps moved to the sd card are lost you can't "revive them" but you can reinstall them from the play store.

Comment: Haha, I see how it is, I put a bounty of 50 points up and immediately get 2 responses. So your suggestion would be to download the apps again, but the data will all still be there? I had flappy bird man...=( Anyway, seeing as you gave me the longest answer (and following the common principle of "quantity is quality" Im going to award you the points. 50 points to gryffindor!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the sd card and SIM, then rooting can do this. It's better to leave them in

This is probably down to the fact that a root upgrade (I.e. Rooting) can change the apps links, meaning a reinstall. I done the same as you, and had to redownload terraria when it was not there but was, and I kept my data. It's kinda like you delete the app, but not the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought in removing the cards I would be totally safe from anything happening to them, seeing as they would be physically not connected to the phone during the root process. I guess my paranoia failed me that day. Most of my apps were un-certified non-google play apps and I forgot where I downloaded some of them (which sucks).